# Basic Container Authentication in Struts

Tags: tomcat, authentication, struts, containers

I need to do basic authentication in struts 1.3.10 + tomcat 8

I tried with below code:

### tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="devteam"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="member1" password="pass1" roles="devteam"/>
  <user username="member2" password="pass2" roles="devteam"/>
  <user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager" />
</tomcat-users>
```

### web.xml

```
          <security-constraint>

                <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>My Application</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                </web-resource-collection>

                <auth-constraint>
                    <role-name>devteam</role-name>
                </auth-constraint>

                <user-data-constraint>
                    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
                </user-data-constraint>

        </security-constraint>

        <login-config>
            <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        </login-config>
```

When i give index.jsp url in browser, i am able to get authentication screen. Even if i feed the username and password as **member1 & pass1** (as mentioned in tomcat-users.xml) login was not successful.

Getting error msg:

```
 http status 401 this request required authentication.
```

in the log I get:

```
org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user
```

Whether I need to do any thing in server.xml?

Comment: What do you mean *login was not successful*? Did you get a error message?

Comment: s. http status 401 this request required authentication.